# How can I make some image processes on video stream from html page

Tags: python, django, image-processing, html5-video

I have a python project in which I get video stream from webcam and make some further image process on it, and I want to turn this project to a web application one, using Django.

To do so, I can access my webcam video stream, thanks to such helpful link [Accessing Your Webcam in HTML](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm), but what I really need is to feed the video stream to my project and show the output stream in a HTML page.

I would appreciate any advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to send video stream from back-end (flask) to front-end(html).

You should visit this helpful link :[Video Streaming with Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

But in summary you can see the code blow. You need a **Response** that takes a function, such as **gen()**, as input. And **gen()** yields stream image.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import Camera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
while True:
    frame = camera.get_frame()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```